# Assign vector<bool>

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to assign a vector bool as follows:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct item {
    int value;
    vector<bool> pb;
    vector<bool> *path = &pb;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<item> dp(10);
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        dp[n].pb = vector<bool>(10);
}
```

It compiles ok but get the following runtime error:

```
An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

The value of `dp` and `n` are

[image]

How can I assign a vector bool to an existing variable?

Comment: What compiler are you using and exactly what version?

Comment: [Cannot repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e0a8983cc772edd) ? (I also ran this in VS2015 and did not get the error you speak of)

Comment: Can't reproduce http://ideone.com/IpEokm

Comment: Can't reproduce with gcc 4.9.2 http://cpp.sh/2xout

Comment: Do you see here [vector<bool>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Comment: I would suggest to use `dp[n].pb = std::move(vector<bool>(10));` explicitly, as that's probably what you really wanted to do (to move 10 values from the local `vector<bool>` into the vector inside item). If you would really want to store that local vector (I mean not just values of it), then the `dp[n].path` would point to the old one, surprising you later. If you want just to init item's vector to 10, then rather do `dp[n].pb.clear(); dp[n].pb.resize(10, false);` without creating/assigning another new local instance.

Comment: @tambre I'm using visual studio 2015 (compiler version - 19.00.24213.1 for x86).

Comment: @Borgleader I've noticed as from the debug window that it works for the first item in dp but fails on the second.

Comment: @Ped7g `vector<bool>(10)` is unnamed and so implicitly an rvalue. `move` will have no effect on it.

Comment: @user3213700: That's strange. [Microsoft's online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) (version: 19.10.24807.0 (x86). Last updated: Dec 7, 2016) compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: @Ped7g tried both suggestions and they both resulted in the same error.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with Visual Studio 2013 (R4). I'd like to point out that `std::vector<bool>` is often (always?) implemented as a specialization which packs the boolean values more efficiently in internal storage.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/

Comment: @user2393256 that it does however version 19.10.24807.0 (x86) is for visual studio 2017.